# What is the best practice for having a unique Id for all tables used by an application?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have an application that runs and stores its objects in 3 different tables `(A, B and C)`.[Visual context](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9xnqG.png)

What I want to do is :
 - To keep the efficiency of an int `PK` for sorting and searching the tables.
 - When a customer calls the customer service by giving it's ID being able to identify if that ID comes from table `A, B or C`.

Here are the potential solutions I came up with :

1. Have a `local id` (for the table) that is an `int` and a `global id` (for the public) that is `local_id + A, B or C` as a suffix. So `10C` is for the `id 10` in `table C`.
2. `PK` of `table A` starts from 1 million; table `B => 2 millions`;...
3. Have a master table that generates ID and identify which ID is for which table.
4. All the ids in table A end with 00, in B with 01, in C with 02,... (not sure if it's faisable?!)

Other options looked at :
 3. `UUID` and `GID` don't answer the need since I won't be able to know in which table the `ID` goes.

My favorite is option 1 since it's not heavy to implement and scalable.

And you what would you do?

EDIT : Please consider that columns in A, B and C are completely different. If it wasn't the case I wouldn't be asking the question.

Comment: Is this mysql, sql-server, or postgres. Cant be all three. Please remove the wrong ones.

Comment: Are you sure you want three tables and not just one table with reference into the company? What happens when you go to 1000 companies, are you planning on 1000 tables? The way you have it you have to duplicate all the other tables that reference A,B or C as well, or not have referential integrity between them. If you really want a unique key across three tables - look up sequences in sql server.

Comment: Definitely not 1.

Comment: @OtmaneZ . . . I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @Strawberry because ?

Comment: Customer service shouldn't need to know or care about your database model. Enter an id, and the application loads data from the correct table. I believe you're solving a problem that doesn't exist. If you run three select statements filtering on the id, only the table with data will return rows.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I said customer service as a shortcut to the customer service application. If I select in the 3 tables the ID for example 10 and all 3 IDs are standard autoincrement values I will have 3 rows one for Table A, one for table B and one for table C.

Comment: This is all getting very theoretical, but it sounds like they are completely different entities. So you'd know by context what you're referring to.(rather than a special range of numbers). However if these things aren't different entities, then I suggest a "master" table that generates the ID and represents the entity, and then add a record with that key to the subtable which contains the attributes you want. Then it's basically a case of "vertical partitioning". BTW I don't see anything wrong with a sparse table with a whole bunch of NULL fields.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is not to organize your data this way. You should not have three tables with unique primary keys. This will lead to lots of trouble, not the least of which is concurrency issues.

You didn't explain why you have three tables that seem to have similar data, but there should be much better solutions: Perhaps having all the records in one table with a column that indicates data `A, B, or C`? Explain your application in more detail if you want a better suggestion.

Comment: Yes @dsShier write, used composite PK where Column one for ID, and second column int type and store ascii value of A,B or C.

Comment: The columns are 100% different from one table to the other. Still believe merging the tree tables with NULL values when it doesn't apply is the best option?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest option 2 little differently. I would suggest you to keep three integer sequences: Seq_A, Seq_B, Seq_C. These sequences will have different ranges:

- Seq_A : 1 to 1,000,000,000
- Seq_B : 1,000,000,001 to 2,147,483,647
- Seq_C : -1 to -2,147,483,648

Have the logic in such a way: The Id should concatenation of: TableName + ID.

- If the table name is C, go for the negative ID in Table C
- If the table name is A and ID < 1 Billion , go for Table A
- If the table name is B and ID > 1 Billion , go for Table B

Answer (score 0):

Actually, a UUID combined with a junction table which relates the ID to the table in which it appears is one option here.  The definition for this junction table might look like:

```
CREATE TABLE id_map(id binary(16), table_name varchar(36));
```

But note that being able to get the table name from the above given a UUID won't be too useful when writing queries.  A more relational way of doing this would be to setup primary foreign key relationships between the A, B, and C tables.  Also, it might actually make more sense here to just have a single table, with a single ID column.  Whether you do that depends on whether the structure of the three tables be very similar or not.

Comment: Tables are 100% different